# Is there a code contract library for JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, validation, javascript, code-contracts

There are lots of *form validation* libraries and jQuery plugins. Though I cannot find a *code contract* library, for validating function arguments.

As an example, to do contract validation in .NET, you could use the outstanding [Conditions library](http://conditions.codeplex.com/). I'm looking for something similar for JavaScript. The closest I can find is [Speks](https://github.com/ecavazos/speks), but its for Node.js and is geared for testing, whereas I need to bake the validation into release code.

Examples of validation methods I need: checks for null, empty, isstring, isnumber, length, min, max, value, less than, greater than, between, not equal, not less than, not greater than, etc.

Comment: PS: I know of the jQuery Validation plugin, but it's used for form validation, and at roughly 20kb, it's not something I want to load on a page that has no forms.

Comment: Right. I've just found [jsContract](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/jsContract) which has lots of validations, but it doesn't have a fluent interface and doesn't use the generally-accepted code contracts terminology. And there's [JavaScript Code Contract Library](http://jstest.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=JavaScript%20Code%20Contract%20Library) which does have a fluent interface, but has some quirks in how it handles nulls. Neither one has been updated after its initial commit. Is anyone using these successfully, or has anyone forked them into a more complete library?

Answer (score 3):

This is a runtime type contracts library which takes on some Haskell like syntax: http://code.google.com/p/ristretto-js.

Answer (score 2):

I was pretty impressed by the implementation put together for this question:

[JavaScript Code Contract Libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445582/javascript-code-contract-libraries)

Example:

```
function syncTime(serverTime, now) {
  Verify.value(serverTime).always().isDate();   // Cannot be undefined or null.
  Verify.value(now).whenDefined().isDate();     // Cannot be null, but must be date when defined.

  //Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just roll a library yourself?

Using a **strategy pattern**, you can easily run a series of methods on a specific value.

Here is a semi-crude example. This obviously needs more error handling and modification, but it provides an idea for what you could build. http://jsfiddle.net/fBfgz/

```
var validator = (function() {
    // Available checks
    var types = {
        isNum: function(value) {
            return !isNaN(value);
        },

        isNull: function(value) {
            return value === null;
        }
    };

   return {
       validate: function (data) {

           var i, len, check, ret;
           for (i = 0, len = data.checks.length; i < len; i += 1) {

               if (types.hasOwnProperty(data.checks[i])) {
                   check = types[data.checks[i]]; 
                   ret = check(data.value);
                   alert(ret);
                   if (!ret) {
                       return false;
                   }
               }
           }
           return true;
       }
   };  
}());

validator.validate({ // will return true
    value: 32,
    checks: ['isNum']
});
validator.validate({ // will return false
    value: 32+'a',
    checks: ['isNum']
});
```

Comment: Yes, currently I'm rolling my own. But it's not perfect, doesn't have all the functionality that I need, and its a pain to maintain it. If there is a widely-used and well-tested library, then I'd rather use that.

Comment: Not to mention, implementing higher order contracts is nontrivial: especially when blame propagation is involved.  Rolling your own is a bad idea once your contracts grow beyond first order.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) for general purpose javascript testing.  Also check out Tim Disney's [contracts.js](https://github.com/disnet/contracts.js), which may be more specific to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

[Sweet-contracts](https://github.com/oleiman/sweet-contracts) does exactly what you want.

Sweet-contracts is a module requiring [sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/), and uses macros to add contracts right into the language. This way you don't have to hack your contracts using existing (and usually insufficient/inefficient) language constructs.

[sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/) allows you to create macros that can expand the language modularly. [This blog post](http://jlongster.com/Stop-Writing-JavaScript-Compilers--Make-Macros-Instead) gives a great introduction to sweet and the power of macros. You can try it out live in your browser [at this address](http://jlongster.com/Writing-Your-First-Sweet.js-Macro).