# Design-by-contract support in coffeescript without language extensions

Tags: coffeescript, dsl, design-by-contract

I consider design-by-contract an useful technique and want to apply it to my coffeescript code.

There is [contracts.coffee](http://disnetdev.com/contracts.coffee/), which looks really nice (like Haskell):

```
id :: (Num) -> Num
id = (x) -> x
```

Downside is that it is a language extension. I'm hesitating because I'm afraid to trade in trouble with tool support. (Am I too conservative?)

Though it really looks great, I would prefer a library solution at the moment. For Ruby, I recently found [contracts.ruby](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby), which shares the same elegance but has the advantage that it is just plain Ruby:

```
require 'contracts'
include Contracts

Contract Num => Num
def id(x) ; x ; end
```

Is there something similiar for coffeescript?

I read about [jsContracts](http://kinsey.no/blog/index.php/2010/02/03/jscontract-code-contracts-for-javascript/) but haven't tested it. Seems to be a useful library, but it lacks the elegance of the Ruby DSL or the contracts.coffee language extension.

**Questions:**

- Is there a syntactically nice design-by-contract library for coffeescript (or Javascript) that integrates seamlessly into the common toolchains?
- Are my concerns about contracts.coffee justified? (If not, it seems to be the perfect fit.)

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Is there a code contract library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597665/is-there-a-code-contract-library-for-javascript)

You can use https://npmjs.org/package/contracts-js, which is the sort of backend, if you will, to contracts.coffee. The downside is that it requires proxies, which are not supported very well in front-end JavaScript.

Seems like an interesting idea for a different kind of library, maybe one that extends functions with contracts...

Answer (score 1):

Its extremely easy to define your own DSL within CoffeeScript. If you want to create a type checking framework you could for example create a class like this

```
class A
     @def foo:
          params: [isNum, isBool,isNotNull]
          body: (x, y, z) -> console.log "foo: #{x}, #{y}, #{z}"
```

@def should create a method named "foo" and check its parameters according to their position by calling the functions given in the "params" array.

Lets write some test first

```
a = new A()
a.foo 3, true, "foo"
a.foo "string", true, "foo"
a.foo 3, "string", "foo"
a.foo 3, false, null
```

Then we need some helper methods that will do the actual parameter checking

```
isNum = (p)-> console.log "p isnt a number its => #{p}" if typeof p != "number"
isBool = (p)-> console.log "p isnt a bool its => #{p}" if typeof p != "boolean"
isNotNull = (p)-> console.log "p is null" if p == null or p == undefined
```

Probably they should do something more useful (like throwing an exception). For our example they should be sufficient.

Now our class A calls a class-method which is not yet defined. We will create a base class for this and the inherit our class A from it

```
class ContractBase
    @def: (fndef)->
        #get the name of the "function definition" object
        #should be the only key
        name = Object.keys(fndef)[0]
        #get the real function body
        fn = fndef[name]["body"]
        #get the params
        params = fndef[name]["params"]

        # create a closure and assign it to the prototype
        @::[name] = ->
            #check the parameters first
            for value, index in arguments
                #get the check at the index of the argument
                check = params[index]
                #and run it if available
                check(value) if check
            #call the real function body
            fn arguments...

#and finally change A to extend from ContractBase
class A extends ContractBase
    ...
```

Obviously there are a few warts in it

- The arguments array and the parameter array can be of different lenght (there is no check for that yet)
- The helper functions should throw an exception
- the helper functions should be combinable like isNotNull(isNum)
- you are circumventing the "normal" way of defining a method so your resulting javascript code will be harder to read and to debug - maybe not

Here is the full running code in one go

```
class ContractBase
    @def: (fndef)->
        name = Object.keys(fndef)[0]
        fn = fndef[name]["body"]
        params = fndef[name]["params"]
        @::[name] = ->
            for value, index in arguments
                check = params[index]
                check(value) if check
            fn arguments...

isNum = (p)-> console.log "p isnt a number its => #{p}" if typeof p != "number"
isBool = (p)-> console.log "p isnt a bool its => #{p}" if typeof p != "boolean"
isNotNull = (p)-> console.log "p is null" if p == null or p == undefined

class A extends ContractBase
    @def foo:
        params: [isNum, isBool,isNotNull]
        body: (x, y, z) -> console.log "foo: #{x}, #{y}, #{z}"

a = new A()
a.foo 3, true, "foo"
a.foo "string", true, "foo"
a.foo 3, "string", "foo"
a.foo 3, false, null
```

Its roughly 1/3 of the length of the corresponding Javascript code and certainly much more readable as it communicates intent much better (imo)